# ios tableview image load duplicate when scrolling tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, if-statement, ios7

I make two custom cell and display in single UITableView in odd even orders, but when i scroll UITableView all image and schedule data color will change randomly and duplicate data will displayed but name,exp., pri-zone, and rate which is in string they all display proper,only image and color of schedule text will change.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {

if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"MyCustomCell";
 TableViewCell *cell=[tblResponseData dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1      
     reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    NSString *imgPath=[[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Pic"];
    // NSString *imgPath=[[appDelegate.arrData  
    objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"image"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[imgPath 
     stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSString *schedule =[[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Schedule"];

        NSArray *strings = [schedule componentsSeparatedByString:@","];


    //NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * resp, NSData * data, NSError  
       * error)
     {
         if(error == NULL){
             // here is our image
             UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
             cell.imgThumbnail.image=image;
         }
         else{
             cell.imgThumbnail.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"no preview 2.jpeg"];
         }
     }];



    for (NSString *item in strings)
    {
        if ([item isEqualToString:@"Su"]) {
            cell.lblsu.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }else if ([item isEqualToString:@"Tu"]){
            cell.lblt.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }else if ([item isEqualToString:@"Th"]){
            cell.lblth.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }
        else if ([item isEqualToString:@"M"]){
            cell.lblm.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }
        else if ([item isEqualToString:@"F"]){
            cell.lblf.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }
        else if ([item isEqualToString:@"S"]){
            cell.lbls.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }
        else if ([item isEqualToString:@"W"]){
            cell.lblw.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }
    }
    cell.lblname.text = [[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Worker Name"];
    cell.lblexperience.text=[[arrData o
   bjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Experience"];
    cell.lblprizone.text=[[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Primary 
     Zone"];
        cell.lblrate.text=[[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Rate"];

    return cell;

   } else {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier1=@"MyCustomCell1";


    TableViewCell *cell1=[tblResponseData d
     equeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];
    if (cell1 == nil)
    {
        cell1 = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 
     reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];
    }

    NSString *imgPath=[[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Pic"];
    // NSString *imgPath=[[appDelegate.arrData 
   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"image"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[imgPath      
    stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    //NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * resp, NSData * data, NSError 
     * error)
     {
         if(error == NULL){
             // here is our image
             UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
             cell1.imgThumbnail.image=image;
         }
         else{
             cell1.imgThumbnail.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"no preview 2.jpeg"];
         }
     }];
    // NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:imgPath];
    //   NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    //   UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imageData];
    // cell.imgThumbnail.image=image;

    NSString *schedule =[[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Schedule"];

    NSArray *strings = [schedule componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    for (NSString *item in strings)
    {
        if ([item isEqualToString:@"Su"]) {
            cell1.lblsu.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }else if ([item isEqualToString:@"Tu"]){
            cell1.lblt.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }else if ([item isEqualToString:@"Th"]){
            cell1.lblth.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }
        else if ([item isEqualToString:@"M"]){
            cell1.lblm.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }
        else if ([item isEqualToString:@"F"]){
            cell1.lblf.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }
        else if ([item isEqualToString:@"S"]){
            cell1.lbls.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }
        else if ([item isEqualToString:@"W"]){
            cell1.lblw.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }
    }

    cell1.lblname.text = [[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Worker N
     ame"];
    cell1.lblexperience.text=[[arrData    
      objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Experience"];
    cell1.lblprizone.text=[[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Primary 
    Zone"];


    cell1.lblrate.text=[[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Rate"];
    return cell1;
  }

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because you load your images by `NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest`. Because the completitionhandler isn't called immediately, but when the data is returned to the request. So the images will be set *after* the cells are loaded.
Try to replace

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * resp, NSData * data, NSError 
     * error)
     {
         if(error == NULL){
             // here is our image
             UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
             cell1.imgThumbnail.image=image;
         }
         else{
             cell1.imgThumbnail.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"no preview 2.jpeg"];
         }
     }];
```

with code that will set `imgThumbnail.image` to an image that is in your project and see whether you still get radomly changing cells.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** You are using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier so the same cell is reused when you are scrolling the tableview and you are send a AsynchronousRequest in that cell so the previously sent cell response we are receiving on another cell so it is showing different result.

**For example:** Cell 2 you are sending a request and then you scrolled the table view so the same cell is reused for cell 10  by that time you will receive the response of cell 2 send request and that image (response data) is displayed in cell 10.

**Solution:** send the request in separate method and save the images in array or dictionary then  reload the corresponding cells based on the the received response.

**For Example:**[EGOImageView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading/tree/master/EGOImageView) is sending request asynchronously and saving in cache and displaying after receiving response please check that once

Answer (score 0):

try this one ,for loading the images From webservices.

```
 NSString *imgUrl = [[arrCategoryDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Image"];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgUrl]];
    if (imgData) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
        if (image) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                CategoryDetailsTableCell *updateCell = (id)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                if (updateCell)
                    updateCell.imgForCategoryDetailCell.image = image;
            });
        }
    }
});
```